# web3 subscribed event fires twice

Tags: reactjs, async-await, promise, blockchain, web3-react

I have a simple event subscription using web3:

```
contract.events.EventName().on('data', async event => {console.log(event)})
```

For some reason though, the event fires twice using web3 (in other words, the event is logged twice in this example), even though the event only fires once on the blockchain.

This also occurs for getPastEvents:

```
  contract.getPastEvents("Event").then(events => console.log(events))
  contract.getPastEvents("Event").then(console.log('a'))
```

Oddly enough, the first is fired twice, the second only once

Comment: First suspicion has to be that two (identical)  event handlers have been attached. Maybe the function that contains the line `contract.events.EventName().on('data', ...)` gets executed twice.

Comment: Nope, only one. If I comment it out nothing fires. If I uncomment it fires twice.

Comment: Is there a `.off()` method (as in jQuery)? If so then try `contract.events.EventName().off('data').on('data', async event => {console.log(event)})` (or similar).

Comment: BTW, commenting/uncommenting demonstrates only that another handler isn't attached by some other line of code. It doesn't prove that this line isn't executed twice.

Comment: There is a .off() method but nothing changed

Comment: Then it sounds like there are two 'data' events. Is there a reason why that should not be the case?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question

Comment: I added another example of web3 firing twice in the original post above. Oddly enough, if you don't pass the callback variable it only fires once

Comment: `.then(console.log('a'))` isn't a properly constructed promise string. `.then()` accepts a function.

Comment: When I asked "is there a reason why that should not be the case?", I mean maybe there's a reason why the event fires twice. Maybe that's the correct behaviour. I can't tell from where I'm sitting.

Comment: True, but at least we know it's not an issue with event listeners, given that getPastEvents just grabs previous events, it doesn't listen to any future one's. What could the issue be then?

Comment: Black magic ... mystery.

Answer (score 0):

The event is not firing twice, you print the log twice.

The first is in this snippet:

```
contract.events.EventName().on('data', async event => {console.log(event)})
```

And the second is in this snippet:

```
contract.getPastEvents("Event").then(events => console.log(events))
```